# [PHP][CRON] How can I reload page in cron?

Tags: php, cron, reload

I made a script which iterates through a couple pages of a third party website looking for data. I have table in database, where I have links to those pages.

There are about **1500 rows** in table, so it's impossible to do it at once. So I have to reload site, changing the offset every time `(offset+=limit)`. It works fine in my browser, but in CRON it doesn't. I can't use JavaScript reload, `meta http-equiv="refresh"`. I try `ignore_user_abort(true);` `set_time_limit(0);` and then sleep, but gives me  504 too. Any ideas how to reload page with new `$_GET['offset']`?

Comment: If you run it with an cronjob, there should usually no executing time limit - so why run it twice?

Comment: because I get random 500 error - so I have to limit the data

Comment: A 500 error isn't random - look inside your servers log file and fix the error instead of do some workarounds

Comment: uh, it's not cool to grab content from third party websites. use an api or rss feed for this kind of stuff. i think you get the 500 cause the third party thinks it's a type of dos

Comment: If you're getting a 504 (a gateway timeout), it's nothing to do with the timeout on your side, it's the remote server. You're either overloading it with requests, or it's actively denying your connections. Either way, you need to ask the owner of the remote site. Don't know them? Then stop scraping their content.

Answer (score 0):

Increase your script execution time limit `set_time_limit ( int $seconds )` so your script will have time to execute. You can even add `sleep(1)` to each iteration so your CPU can take a breath.
If that doesn`t  work check php error log for the problem.

Comment: Really not sure about 'so your CPU can take a breath'!

Comment: its optional :)